# HTTP 500 error after installing Polylang plugin in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, polylang

I have installed Polylang plugin in my WordPress website. But once I activates the plugin then WordPress admin panel is showing HTTP 500 error. Frontend of the website is opening fine.

I have tried by increasing memory_limit to 256M in wp-config file but it has not solved the issue.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Remove plugin folder and upload again over FTP then test again just in case. If that doesn't help check PHP version and modules on your hosting. May be due outdated PHP or some module is missing that plugin require.

Comment: Tried by removing plugin and upload again over FTP but no luck